# Unable to read entire response body

Tags: http, go

I'm trying to make a straightforward request to an API, which works just fine in Postman, and weirdly occasionally works in my app, but usually fails when trying to parse the JSON because only about half the response is being read into the `body` variable. When the entire response is read everything works fine. I'm not really sure what if anything I'm doing wrong here, or if there's anything else I can do differently to make sure that the entire response is parsed.

```
  var reqBody = []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{
      "methodName": "GetPropertyList",
      "params": {
          "token_key": "%v",
          "token_secret": "%v"
      }
  }`, token, secret))
  
  req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", proxy_url, bytes.NewBuffer(reqBody))
  req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  
  client := http.Client{}
    
  resp, err := client.Do(req)
  if err != nil {
      log.Printf("Couldn't get property field list: %v")
  } else {
      defer resp.Body.Close()
      body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

      bodyStr := string(body)
      log.Printf("BODY: %v", len(bodyStr))
      
      var respModel ResponseModel
      err = json.Unmarshal(body, &respModel) //Error happens here
  }
```

Comment: Do not ignore the error returned from `ReadAll`

Comment: Check the ReadAll error per previous comment.  What is the error returned from json.Unmarshal?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using `json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&respModel)`

The full code would then look like:

```golang
    var token, secret, proxy_url string
    var reqBody = []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{
        "methodName": "GetPropertyList",
        "params": {
            "token_key": "%v",
            "token_secret": "%v"
        }
    }`, token, secret))

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", proxy_url, bytes.NewBuffer(reqBody))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := http.Client{}

    var respModel ResponseModel
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Couldn't get property field list: %v", err)
    } else {

        err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&respModel)
    }
```